# Como criar um hash usando a biblioteca hashlib usando o metodo "time.time()" em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

Olá, estou com a seguinte situação:

- Tenho que criar um `hexdigest` de uma concatenação de 2 números transformados em string.
- Para isso, devo utilizar a biblioteca `hashlib` e o projeto deve ser em python.

Segue meu código até o momento:

```py
import time
import hashlib

num1 = 123456
num2 = time.time()

str1 = str(num1)
str2 = str(num2)

hash = hashlib.sha1(str1 + str2)
hexhash = hash.hexdigest()

print(hexhash)
```

O problema é que ao tentar executar o código acima, está retornando a mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

O que preciso fazer para consguir criar esse `hexdigest` usando essas variáveis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suas strings estão no formato errado. Elas devem ser encodadas antes de aplicar o hash através de um dos seguintes métodos:

```
(str1).encode('utf-8')
```

ou

```
num1 = b'123456'
```

Ou você pode fazer tudo em uma linha só através de

```
hexhash = hashlib.sha1((str1 + str2).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: hum.. não sabia do método encode... tem 1 semana que estou mexendo com python, muito obrigado!